# Access to the registry key 'HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\office\15.0\outlook' is denied

Tags: c#, outlook, registry, unauthorizedaccessexcepti

I am creating a plugin for outlook using C#.

I want to programmatically add a subkey under the registry `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\office\15.0\outlook` to always enable the plugin in outlook.

My code snippet is

```
string SUB_KEY_NAME = @"addinlist";

RegistryKey regkey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"Software\Policies\Microsoft\office\15.0\outlook", true);           

regkey = regkey.CreateSubKey(SUB_KEY_NAME);

regkey.SetValue("Plugin Name", "1");
```

But it throws

> System.UnauthorizedAccessException' exception and shows "Access to the registry key 'HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\office\15.0\outlook' is denied"

can anyone help me?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you check you have permission to access that key?

Comment: As i am the admin,I have permission to access the key.

Answer (score 2):

Try to close and reopen Visual Studio using **run as an administrator**. Then re-run your code.

Comment: When i run in administrator mode , i can test whether the subkey is created in my machine. But will the plugin work in all machines.

Comment: Yes, if the plugin is ran as administrator. You must be executing code as an administrator in order to change the registry keys. You can try to compile and run it to see what happens. And please accept the answer if this helped you ;)